# Simpson's 1/3 Rule

Tags: fitting, homework

[image]

Hi. I'm trying to figure out how to code Simpson's rule in mathematica.

Comment: I've tried SimpsonsRule[2 \[Pi]x Sqrt[1 + (-\[Pi]sin (\[Pi]x/10)^2)], {x, 0, 5}]

Comment: I've also tried f[x_] := 2 \[Pi]x Sqrt[1 + (-\[Pi]sin (\[Pi]x/10)^2)]
SimpsonIntegral[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, 8] // Simplify

Comment: Best to add what you have tried to the question itself and additionally show the results.

Comment: Clear[a, b, n]
SIMP[0, 5, 
  8] := (1/3) Sum[
   2 \[Pi]x Sqrt[1 + (-\[Pi]sin (\[Pi]x/10)^2)][
      0 + (2 i - 2) (5 - 0)/8] + 
    4*2 \[Pi]x Sqrt[1 + (-\[Pi]sin (\[Pi]x/10)^2)][
      0 + (2 i - 1) (5 - 0)/8] + 
    2 \[Pi]x Sqrt[1 + (-\[Pi]sin (\[Pi]x/10)^2)][
      0 + 2 i (5 - 0)/n], {i, 1, 8/2}] (5 - 0)/8

I tried and it didn't give me an outcome!

Comment: @Jagra the outputs were what Inputted but implified

Comment: yes I just added my formula and my a,b,n in the equation.

Comment: WL is case sensitive, `Sin`, not `sin`.

Comment: I suggest you ask your question [here](https://community.wolfram.com/). You can attach a notebook with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpson 1/3 rule for an integral `Integrate[fun[x], {x, a, b}]` is :

```
int = 1/3 (b - a)/2 (f[a] + 4 f[(a + b)/2] + f[b])
```

Therefore, for your case :

```
f[x_] = 10 Cos[Pi x / 10]; 
fun[x_] = 2 Pi x Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2];
sim[fun_, a_, b_] = 
  1/3 (b - a)/2 (fun[a] + 4 fun[(a + b)/2] + fun[b]);
```

Now, I assume that m ==1 and the integration range is 0 to 5.  If we divide this interval
into  8 sub intervals of length 5/8  we get with Simpsons rule:

```
Sum[sim[fun, (i - 1) 5/8, i 5/8], {i, 8}] // N
(* 216.362 *)
```

Compare this with the output of `NIntegrate`:

```
NIntegrate[2 Pi x Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2], {x, 0, 5}]
(* 216.363 *)
```

you see that for this case Simsons rule is astonishingly accurate.